# What is Geometry smoothing in FBX export options?

Tags: export, .fbx

I tried to found some real explaination or even single tip. But I don't know what they do or even when I should use one of them.

[image: Export Smoothing]

Blender wiki is empty at the moment, [Blender wiki: FBX](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html#geometry)

Can someone explain roughly or in details what each one of them do?

Smoothing options:

- Normals only
- Face
- Edge